# Что мы выделяем при постановке тире перед частицей НЕ — подлежащее или сказуемое?

Tags: тире, частица-не

Постановка тире при наличии частицы НЕ Розенталь связывает **с актуализацией сказуемого.** Но мне не совсем понятна эта точка зрения, так как логическое ударение при наличии тире и паузы  падает **на подлежащее.**

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92

Постановка тире в этом случае имеет целью **логически и интонационно подчеркнуть сказуемое:** Но объяснение — не оправдание (М. Г.); Его взгляды на семейный этикет — не предрассудок ли это?;

Примеры:

1) **Тире ставится**

Онегин — не Мельмот, не Чайльд-Гарольд, не демон, не пародия, не модная причуда... (Белинский).

Я — не муж, не жених твой, не друг (Блок).

Лес — не просто растительность на почве.  Лес — ничем не заменимая экологическая система планеты.

Писательство — не ремесло и не занятие. Писательство — призвание.

2) **Нет тире**

Москва не безмолвная громада камней, составленных в симметричном порядке.

Узнав, что Наумов не инженер, а конногвардеец, она сожалела о том, что высказала свою тайну.

Природа не храм, а мастерская, и человек в ней работник.

3) **В этих предложениях возможны оба варианта?** Что выделяется при постановке тире?

Душа Печорина не каменистая почва, но засохшая от зноя земля.

Онегин не холодный, не сухой, не бездушный человек

Comment: "Постановка тире в этом случае имеет целью логически и интонационно подчеркнуть сказуемое" (Розенталь). Подчеркнуть логически - да, понимаю ( "Я —не муж." Тут важно, что не муж). Подчеркнуть интонационно - не понимаю. Ударение падает над "я". Может, предшествующая пауза привлекает внимание к сказуемому?

Comment: Вариант без паузы и тире.  Я не мУж, не женИх твой, не дрУг. Местоимения "я" никак не выделяется,  ударение падает только на сказуемое. А если поставить тире, то ударение падает и на подлежащее, и на сказуемое, то есть они оба выделены. Но при сравнении вариантов дополнительное выделение (АКТУАЛИЗАЦИЮ) при постановке тире получает именно подлежащее.

Answer (score 1):

> Тире обычно не ставится, если перед сказуемым стоит отрицание.
>   Постановка тире в этом случае имеет целью логически и интонационно
>   подчеркнуть сказуемое...

*Подчеркнуть логически* в примере "Но объяснение — не оправдание" может означать противопоставление мнению собеседника (высказанному или предполагаемому) или широко распространённому мнению. *Интонационное подчёркивание* может ограничиваться *увеличением паузы* по сравнению со случаем нейтрального утверждения (предполагающего, что собеседник согласится), вряд ли обязательно подчёркивать слова выраженным ударением. Что именно подчёркивается при отделении сказуемого от подлежащего? Скорее, *сказуемое*: в силу упомянутого противопоставления, именно в группе сказуемого содержится информация, которая говорящим предполагается *новой или неожиданной* для собеседника, в то время как подлежащее названо нейтральным образом (здесь: [вот вы тут объяснили своё поведение,] но объяснение...).

Comment: Сравните два варианта: (1) Но объяснЕнеие - не оправдАние.  Два интонационных ударения,  два смысловых центра, так как перед паузой  голос повышается в обязательном порядке. (2) Но объяснение не оправдАние. При отсутствии интонационного выделения подлежащего единственным смысловым центром является  сказуемое,